Find truncated strings for provided word in python
I am attempting to do a string comparison that checks for common truncated words in the string while doing a word by word comparison.
Does a python library exist for finding variations of truncated words in the english language?
if "inc" in truncated_stings_for("Incorporated"):
    pass

More examples of potential truncated words in a string below for clarity purposes. I will be finding string A using string B:
a = "LINCOLN ELECTRIC HOLDINGS"
b = "LINCOLN ELEC HLDGS"

a = "INCYTE CORP"
b = "Incyte Co."

a = "RLJ Lodging Trust"
b = "RLJ LODGING TR"

a = "KRATOS DEFENSE & SECURITY"
b = "KRATOS DEFENSE & SEC"

a = "Brookdale Senior Living"
b = "BROOKDALE SR LIVING"

Note: I do NOT have a complete list of potential words that I might come across that might be truncated, so this isn't something I can hard code in variations for.

This is a natural language problem, there may be tools in those libraries.

@Barmar, I am attempting to find an example of a similar natural language library. Do you have any references you can provide to help me start looking in the correct direction?

I don't do NLP programming, so I can't help you there. And requests for references are off-topic here, so this question will likely be closed soon.

You could use AI to build your list of truncated strings. Ask it for the standard truncations for the most used words in English, etc.

@nicomp, That's an interesting idea. If nothing better turns out, I might do exactly that. Though I expect it would be pretty slow to run

@brw59 I just tried it with Gemini and it's more condescending than posting an SO question. It lectured me about using truncated words. Ugh.  ;)

Problem is some of these are context dependent.  For instance, OMG can mean Oh My God or Object Management Group or a manufacturing company in the US.

@nicomp, yeah, I would expect a fair amount of parsing would be required after a consistent question was structured for the AI. Not an ideal solution since it's hard to guarantee a response structure

@cup, I think I would ignore this problem if I could get a complete truncated list of a provided string. Besides, usually I'll be searching the other way: 'Object Management Group' --> 'OMG', not visa versa

If you could guarantee that all the letters of the “truncated” word were present in the full word, then it would just be a subsequence check. Unfortunately, as this is natural language, I doubt it would be so simple. For example, “and” can be abbreviated as “&” or even “/“ depending on context. Other words like “the” might be left out entirely. Some abbreviations span multiple words, like LLC. I am sure there are many other pathological examples.
